# How to bypass download restrictions other than using VPN?

Tags: networking, download, quota

Its possible that someone has blocked downloading on the network I use.  But it  works to listen to radio streaming or youtube in high quality.

What I tried and does NOT work:
-browser download
-shell download
-torrent download
-virtual machine download
-changing mac address

What works:
-VPN download (of the same files, but I dont have a subscription)

Maybe I could change some ports, or how could I bypass that restriction ?

Comment: or maybe the restriction exists for a reason and you shouldn't try to bypass it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the proxy software like `Ultrasurf` or use the `proxy IP address` on your browser. This should bypass the restrictions.

Comment: Its worth noting though that using proxy software normally revokes your privacy. A VPN would be a more encompassing option